# angularjs bind data only on events

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form, I wan to bind its values only when the user click on a button.
And when the user choose to reset / cancel, I want to go back to original model data.
How can it be done? http://jsfiddle.net/1y9ft817/
Thanks

```
<div ng-controller="MyCont" ng-app>
<form>
    <input type="number" min="0" max="50" value="{{value}}" ng-model="value" />{{value}}
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="bind the data" />
    <input type="reset" value="reset back to 15" />
</form>
```

```
function MyCont($scope) {
    $scope.value = 15;
};
```

Comment: do you want to update it on blur ? or only when clicks on button ?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Comment: @NarekMamikonyan - on click

Answer (score 0):

```
function MyCont($scope) {
    $scope.value = 15;
    $scope.tmpValue = $scope.value;
};


<div ng-controller="MyCont" ng-app>
<form>
    <input type="number" min="0" max="50" ng-model="tmpValue" />{{tmpValue}}
    <br />
    <btn ng-click="value = tmpValue">Submit</btn>
    <btn ng-click="tmpValue = value">Reset</btn>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need model to keep track both old and new Value

```
<div ng-controller="MyCont" ng-app>
    <form>
        <input type="number" min="0" max="50" value="{{value.newVal}}" ng-model="value.newVal" />{{value.newVal}}
        <br />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="bind the data" ng-click="bindVal()" />
        <input type="reset" ng-click="resetVal()"value="reset back to 15" />
    </form>
</div>

function MyCont($scope) {
    $scope.value = {
        oldVal:15,
        newVal:15
    }
    $scope.bindVal=function(){
    $scope.value.oldVal=$scope.value.newVal;

    }
    $scope.resetVal=function(){
    $scope.value.newVal=$scope.value.oldVal;
    }
};
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xj5b0ucb/):-

Comment: The reset is working, but when I change the text the {{value.newVal}} changes as well, it supposed to be changed after on click.

Comment: Simple use {{value.oldVal}} in the place where you are showing the value instead of {{value.newVal}}  http://jsfiddle.net/xj5b0ucb/1/

Answer (score 0):

Stemming off of Squiroid's but fixed the reset.

```
function MyCont($scope) {
$scope.value = {
    origVal:15,
    oldVal:15,
    newVal:15
}
$scope.bindVal=function(){
$scope.value.oldVal=$scope.value.newVal;

}
$scope.resetVal=function(){
$scope.value.oldVal=$scope.value.origVal;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gzuhtx9c/

Answer (score 0):

If I got your needs correctly (you want to add/remove connection between input value and displayed value by clicking the btns) you can implement it like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCont" ng-app>
<form>  
    <input type="number" min="0" max="50" value="{{value}}" data-ng-model="value"/> 
    {{displayValue}}
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="bind the data" data-ng-click="bindVal()" />
    <input type="reset" value="reset back to 15" data-ng-click="resetVal()" />
</form>
```

```
function MyCont($scope) {
var isValueReallyBinded = true,
    initialValue = 15;
$scope.value = initialValue;

$scope.$watch('value', function (newVal, oldVal) {
    if(isValueReallyBinded) {
        $scope.displayValue = $scope.value;
    }
    else {
        $scope.displayValue = initialValue;
    }
});

$scope.bindVal = function () {
    isValueReallyBinded = true;
    $scope.displayValue = $scope.value;
};
$scope.resetVal = function () {
    isValueReallyBinded = false;
    $scope.displayValue = initialValue;
};
};
```